# Error minifying Android app with R8 after upgrading Android Gradle Plugin to 8.1.0

Tags: build, proguard, minify, android-app-bundle, android-r8

After updating the Android Gradle Plugin in my Android app project to **8.1.0** I'm encountering an error during the release build when the *minifyReleaseWithR8* task is executed.

The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
Library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED
```

I made *Clean Project*, *Rebuild Project*, and *Invalidate Caches*, but the issue persists.

How can I resolve these errors and successfully minify my release build with R8?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please check https://issuetracker.google.com/200069038#comment4, to see it that is the same issue as you are having.